# Execute Many to Many migration using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize-cli

this is my first time using sequelize and I want to run a many to many migration. This is the setup of my models:

`models/collection.js`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Collection = sequelize.define('Collection', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Collection.belongsToMany(Post, { through: CollectionPost, foreignKey: 'collection_id' });
      }
    }
  });
  return Collection;
};
```

and `models/post.js`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Post.belongsToMany(Collection, { through: CollectionPost, foreignKey: 'post_id' });
      }
    }
  });

  return Post;
};
```

I understand that sequelize has `sync` method that syncs the models with migrations.However I want to sync only once and hence I wrote this small script to that:

```
const models = require('../models');

function test() {
    return models.sequelize.sync((err, response) => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('.........');
      console.log(response);
    });
}
test();
```

However, this is not creating the `CollectionPost` table. What am I missing ?

Comment: wich version of sequelize are you using ?

Comment: I am using  "sequelize": "^4.2.1" and "sequelize-cli": "^2.7.0"

Comment: from version 4 classMethods and istanceMethods are removed.
For more information please take a look here:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html

Comment: I see ! thanks for pointing to that :)